How do I pause an object along a path and then have it continue?
I have looked at many YouTube videos and still can’t get my object to pause.
I have a top down view of a simple cube, created a path, gave the cube a follow path constraint, put a key frame at 1 for the start at offset 0, put a key frame at the end at offset of -100.  Then I put a key frame where I want it to pause midway on the path, copied that offset, created another key frame a ways further and copied the offset.
Those are now connected by an orange bar.  When I play the animation, it just moves right through the “pause” keyframes without stopping.  I’ve tried a million different combinations and still can’t get it to work.
This is a simple example of something much more complicated I’m working on.

pls provide blend file, thx.

Hello maybe you have pressed on the Animate Path button of the constraint, in that case you need to remove the Generator modifier in the Graph Editor, but please share your file



You pressed the Animate Path button of the constraint, it has assigned a Generator modifier to the curve, select it, go into the Graph Editor, open the N panel > Modifiers and remove the modifier:

Now you can either use the constraint Offset value to move the object (like you've done) or the Evaluation Time of the curve under Data > Path Animation.

This was so very helpful.  I understand now there are a number of different ways to set keyframes and what I did wrong was not use G+X to move the object.  Instead, I was animating it too soon and moving it with the timeline as you saw.  After you pointed me in the right direction, I ended up adding a curve modifier and then setting up my keyframes.  First time in a long list of attempts prior to getting help here, I actually got it to pause.  So grateful, moonboots!
